# Blob file limit for query with BlobClientBase.queryWithResponse()

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-for-java

I am using the code sample from BlobClientBase.queryWithResponse(BlobQueryOptions queryOptions, Duration timeout, Context context) Method to try to query data from a blob file on Azure Blob Storage. I was able to successfully retrieve data from smaller files such as file size of 1KB. But when I try to query larger files such as file size of 1MiB, I get an exception stating record is larger than supported. Is there a size limit to the blob file I can query using this method?

Answer (score 0):

> I try to query larger files such as file size of 1MiB, I get an exception stating record is larger than supported. Is there a size limit to the blob file I can query using this method?

Yes, according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/query-blob-contents):

- [`queryWithResponse(BlobQueryOptions queryOptions, Duration timeout, Context context)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase?view=azure-java-stable#:%7E:text=queryWithResponse(BlobQueryOptions%20queryOptions%2C%20Duration%20timeout%2C%20Context%20context)) this method queries an entire blob into an output stream.
- The maximum size of the query expression is 256KiB.

References: [BlobClientBase Class - queryWithResponse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase?view=azure-java-stable), [BlobClientBase.queryWithResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.storage.blob.specialized.blobclientbase.querywithresponse?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-storage-blob-specialized-blobclientbase-querywithresponse(com-azure-storage-blob-options-blobqueryoptions-java-time-duration-com-azure-core-util-context)) and [BlobClientBase.java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/src/main/java/com/azure/storage/blob/specialized/BlobClientBase.java)